# Why are there two $this in the last statement in this php code?

Tags: php, this

```
 parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l('Responsive products featured');
    $this->description = $this->l('Displays featured products and categories in your homepage.');
    $this->

    include_once($this->local_path.'/classes/ResponsiveHomeFeaturedClass.php');
```

You will see that it is difficult to understand why the last statement uses two $this ?

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but shouldn't that generate a syntax error? Is there a method `include_once()` in the class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm not sure if you have an error in your pasted code, since `include_once` is a commonly used built-in function, but I *suppose* it could also be an instance function on an object...)

There's no reason why any one line of code can't reference `$this` twice, or as many times as it needs to.  `$this` is just a reference to an object.  So in this line of code:

```
$this->include_once($this->local_path.'/classes/ResponsiveHomeFeaturedClass.php');
```

It's just calling the `include_once` function and passing it a value, which includes the `local_path` value.  This would accomplish the same thing:

```
$some_local_path = $this->local_path;
$this->include_once($some_local_path.'/classes/ResponsiveHomeFeaturedClass.php');
```

But it would be using an unnecessary temporary variable.  `include_once` is just a function, and `local_path` is just a value.  The latter can be used as a parameter for the former.

Comment: You could just have send her(?) one of your old PHP beginners guides ... anyway +1

Comment: @djot: I don't have any old PHP beginners guides.  Though the question has little to do with PHP and more to do with object references in general.  Any OOP tutorial should be able to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298507/php-reserved-names-functions) have `include_once` as your method because it is [reserved keyword](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)!

The following code

```
class Test {
  function include_once() {
  }
}
```

will NOT work:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_INCLUDE_ONCE, expecting T_STRING
```

It is a very good thing to keep you away from troubles.

The code in question would work if `include_once` would indeed be a method (which it can't be), it is, however, not a good practice to insert an empty line.

Concerning `$this` - it is part of your method or property call, so in general it can be used as many times as you need to refer to your methods or properties (from the same class instance).