# Is there any way to get rid of the PHP parent keyword?

Tags: php, yii, keyword

I have a model generated as **Parent** from Yii.

```
class Parent extends AppModel {}
```

When I used it as follows, I got an error.

```
$parent = new Parent();
```

> *Fatal error: Cannot use 'Parent' as class name as it is reserved in E:\Customer\Qelasy\Project\QelasySecurity\web\SourceCode\protected\modules\user\models\Parent.php on line 14*

As I understand, this is because `Parent` is a keyword in PHP, and Yii has generated this. Is there any workaround to make it work with `Parent` without changing the model name into **Parents**?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298507/php-reserved-names-functions)... have a look at the link in the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You cannot name a class `Parent`, period. It's a reserved keyword in the core language. Unless you change the core language, you cannot circumvent this restriction. Since class names aren't case sensitive, what would the following statement do?

```
public function foo() {
    parent::bar();
}
```

Therefore: no naming of classes that clash with keywords.

Answer (score 2):

No, you will have to rename your model to something else. Try and be more specific with your class name. What is this a parent of?

MyParent? UserParent? AppParent? Maybe [use a synonym](http://thesaurus.com/browse/parent)?

Answer (score 1):

`Parent` is reserverd php keyword, cannot able use it as class name, use different name ,

```
 class myclass extends AppModel {}

  $myclass = new myclass();
```

Here is the link, you can find the list of keywords :http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php