# Laravel - name a model using a reserved word

Tags: php, laravel

I know it's [not possible to use a reserved word in PHP as class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298507/can-i-use-php-reserved-names-for-my-functions-and-classes), but my Laravel app enables managing of courses and classes, so I have a database table called `classes`, a `ClassController` and hopefully a `Class` model. However, in Laravel, my model has to be named `Class` which is not allowed in PHP:

```
class Class extends Model {}
```

Using a synonym, the closest being `Lecture`, still doesn't seem right.

Is there a Laravel workaround to this?

Comment: `in Laravel, my model has to be named Class` you can name the model whatever you want, call it ClassModel?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Laravel doesn't force you to use specific names for your models or controllers. It's just a convention. You can name your model whatever you want it to be. the only amend you will have to make is to declare `protected $table = 'classes'` in your model

Comment: Super cool this helped me a lot. Is this the only puprose of declaring `protected $table` in model? When we want to use a reserved word? Do you know where I can find a list of reserved words for laravel? Apparently `Entity` was one.

Comment: @Noitidart the purpose of having `protected $table` declared is to  override naming convention that Laravel follows. Laravel will assume that your table name is pluralized version of your model name, i.e. you may have model called `Video`, then it's going to look for table `videos`. but if you want to name your model `VideoModel` it's going to look for `video_models` table. this is where you define -- nope, it's still just `protected $table = 'videos';`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can have model named `Entity` tho. the only restrictions are the PHP reserved words http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php

Comment: Thanks @Almazik for a detailed description for a new comer like me this is invaluble! I kept having problems with an Entity model because it was looking for plural of "entities" rather then "entitys" ("ies" vs "ys").

Comment: @Noitidart exactly, it's smart to know that this is `ies` in this case. so again, `protected $table` to the rescue

Comment: That is so cool, I learned that the hard way haha. Is there a rulebook for this in the docs somewhere? Or is it just all words ending in `y` get `ies`?

Comment: I'm not sure about the rule book, I guess that's just general english language rules