# Laravel 5.7: Defining Relationships with Models having Reserved Names

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, laravel-5.7

I went through this post...
[Laravel - name a model using a reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33129425/laravel-name-a-model-using-a-reserved-word)

But this doesn't provide a solution of defining relationships.

I have a Model name `Class.php`
And I have to Relate it with Student & ClassAllocation

Here is my Relationship defined in Student.php:

```
/**
 * Check the Class allocated to Student
 *
 *@return void
 */
public function class()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Class', 'class_allocations');
}
```

I have tried everything and I don't want to change my Model name now. How do I make this work? I keep getting this error on tinker:

> PHP Error:  syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in /home/vagrant/Homestead/app/app/Class.php on
>   line 7

Comment: What wasn't explained in the related post?  You can't name functions and classes reserved words in PHP, has nothing to do with Laravel.  You'd have the same issues with other languages so you need to name them something else.

Comment: Ok @Aaryan, post your Class model as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't use reserved words!!!!

As a suggestion (what I did in my project) is use the name for the model 'ClassRoom' or something.

And the name for the relationship 'classRooms()' or something.