# How to use builtin function name inside a class as a method name

Tags: php

I have a class called `Validation` and a method named `array`. Since `array` is a builtin function in PHP its throwing an error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'array' (T_ARRAY), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\mvc\app\validation.php on
>   line 82

Is there a way I can use array as a method name?

```
//This is a class
class Validation extends Controller{

    //This is a method
    public function array( $field, $name ){

    }

}
```

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298507/can-i-use-php-reserved-names-for-my-functions-and-classes

Comment: not possible use builtin function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, PHP doesn't have a way of escaping reserved words so that they can be used as class/method/etc names.

> You cannot use any of the following words as constants, class names, function or method names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to confusion.
>
> As of PHP 7.0.0 these keywords are allowed as as property, constant, and method names of classes, interfaces and traits, except that class may not be used as constant name.

See http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php for a full list.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WVgvh