# who can help me? i having this error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-5

> syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR), expecting identifier
>   (T_STRING)

```
  public function for($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming it to something else than the PHP `for` loop?

Comment: What are you trying to do actually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use PHP reserved names for my functions and classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298507/can-i-use-php-reserved-names-for-my-functions-and-classes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for` is a reserved keyword in php (and most other languages). This means that you can't use it as a function or variable name. If you rename your function to something like `setUser` it should all be fine.

```
public function setUser($user) {
    $this->user = $user;
    return $this;
}
```

You can find a list of other reserved keywords here: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php