# Can I remove a php function?

Tags: php

I would like to use:

```
function list(args);
```

but `list` is a reserved word.

Can I remove the list function from PHP, disable it, or otherwise?

Comment: No but if you press Ctrl+H in your editor you can replace all instances of **list** with, say **list_** in your project.

Comment: Dup

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302771/is-it-possible-to-escape-a-method-name-in-php-to-be-able-to-have-a-method-name

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5298507/php-reserved-names-functions

Comment: yeah i'm all about the epic, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't, nor should you want to. Redefining built-in functions is a Bad Thing, especially something as fundamental as `list`, which isn't a function at all - it's a language construct.

All you can do is come up with a unique name for your function.

Answer (score 6):

In a normal situation, no, you cannot *remove* a function.

Using the [**runkit**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension *(which I've virtually never seen installed on a server -- and absolutely never on a production server !)*, you'd have the [**`runkit_function_remove()`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-remove.php) function, that could help.

Same with other debugging extensions, such as [**APD**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apd.php), which provides the [**`override_function()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.override-function.php), btw.

With PHP >= 5.3 and namespaces, you could also re-define a function, inside your own namespace, that could sort of *replace* the one of the global namespace.

But note that **[`list()`][5] is not a function** : it is a **language construct** -- and, as such, it doesn't behave like functions...

As a sidenote : even if possible *(and/or when possible)*, replacing an existing function with your own, that doesn't do the same thing, is not a good idea : people reading your code, maintaining it, will have more difficulties understanding what it does !

Answer (score 5):

You can only rename/remove core functions using the runkit or APD extensions. list isn't actually a function, but a language construct, so you can't rename it even with those extensions.

You should really be using a better choice of names for your own functions... list() isn't particularly meaningful. list what?

Comment: list isn't meaningful!? are you joking. what about /users/list/ as a url

Comment: /users/list/ as a url gives you an indication of what is being listed (users)... simply calling a function list() without context tells you nothing about what it lists